# Can't open XAMPP localhost page Windows 7

Tags: database

I use Windows 7 64 bit and installed XAMPP win32 5.6.11.0.

In control panel v3.2.1.

if click "stop" apache and mysql and type http://localhost, then I can open http://localhost/dashboard/ page, but cannot open myPHP admin. 
if use "start" apache and mysql, then it says "Unable to connect"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question:

'I use Windows 7 **64** bit and installed XAMPP win**32**'

```
Win64 is the XAMPP you need
```